# Strapi Deployment on aws Amplify

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-amplify, strapi

I want to know can you deploy your strapi project on AWS Amplify? I am trying to deploy my project. I went with the default configuration and also added all the env and the thing is it did get built and deployed but when I go to the generated URL it shows the page cannot be found here are some logs from the build phase:

```
"styled-components@5.3.3".
2023-10-18T04:53:59.098Z [INFO]: [5/5] Building fresh packages...
2023-10-18T04:54:54.565Z [INFO]: Done in 84.59s.
2023-10-18T04:54:54.579Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: preBuild
                                 # Starting phase: build
2023-10-18T04:54:54.580Z [INFO]: # Executing command: yarn run build
2023-10-18T04:54:54.701Z [INFO]: yarn run v1.22.0
2023-10-18T04:54:54.726Z [INFO]: $ strapi build
2023-10-18T04:54:56.373Z [WARNING]: /bin/sh: hostname: command not found
2023-10-18T04:54:56.407Z [INFO]: Building your admin UI with development configuration...
2023-10-18T04:54:57.020Z [INFO]: [info] [webpackbar] Compiling Webpack
2023-10-18T04:55:11.148Z [INFO]: [success] [webpackbar] Webpack: Compiled successfully in 14.13s
2023-10-18T04:55:12.999Z [INFO]: Admin UI built successfully
2023-10-18T04:55:13.066Z [INFO]: Done in 18.37s.
2023-10-18T04:55:13.071Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: build
2023-10-18T04:55:13.076Z [INFO]: ## Build completed successfully
2023-10-18T04:55:13.076Z [INFO]: # Starting caching...
2023-10-18T04:55:13.080Z [INFO]: # Creating cache artifact...
2023-10-18T04:55:25.089Z [INFO]: # Created cache artifact
2023-10-18T04:55:25.180Z [INFO]: # Uploading cache artifact...
2023-10-18T04:55:26.961Z [INFO]: # Uploaded cache artifact
2023-10-18T04:55:26.961Z [INFO]: # Caching completed
2023-10-18T04:55:26.968Z [INFO]: # No custom headers found.
2023-10-18T04:55:26.971Z [WARNING]: !! No index.html detected in deploy folder: /codebuild/output/src2276763120/src/checking/
```